# Binary digits separator and convert to decimal using power function in C

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I'm very new to C programming and I was asked to do a program that separates the binary numbers being input into their own digits by 3 spaces as well as convert it into their decimal equivalent.
E.g if the number of digits is 6 and the binary number is 110111 the printout will be
1   1   0   1   1   1
The Decimal Equivalent is 55

[So far i've only done the converter, if i put the digits separator in it either one of them does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qndxI.png)

I'm currently stuck at making both the separator and the converter work at the same time. Thanks for the help beforehand.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: All numbers are binary in C. You can chose to represent them in other bases when doing input/output or when typing constants in the source. Do you actually meant to ask how to convert a _binary number string_ to another string format? Also, this will indeed get closed unless you post the code as text.

Answer (score 0):

Change inner `while loop` condition:

```
while(binary > 0)
{
     d = binary % 10;
     decimal += d * pow(2, counter);
     binary /= 10;
     counter++;
}
```